# Установка убунты

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Убунту открывается только с флешки, посмотрел свои диски, и там заметил что диск sda7 выделено 100 гб под Linux. Но как его открыть? Без флешки открывается grub2 в котором не понять что делать. Прочитал 50 гайдов не помогло

Comment: Ничего не понятно, еще раз. Вы установили убунту. При установке ошибок не было? Что вы видите при включении компьютера, grub? В каком виде? Раз ничего не понятно, значит в виде консоли? Что написано слева от `>` при вводе команды, `grub` или `grub recovery`?

Comment: Открывается просто окно grub2, в ней написано  Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For
         the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command
         completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
         completions of a device/filename. ]

Comment: Что по поводу остальных вопросов?

Comment: Когда открывается линукс через флешку, видно, что на одном из дисков установлена Linux. (но лучше разробраться как выйти из граба и открыть линукс)

Comment: При установке ошибок не было? В грабе, что написано слева от `>` при вводе команды, `grub` или `grub recovery`?

Comment: Просто grub выходит

Comment: Ясно. При установке линукса ошибок не было? Не писало, что он не может поставить grub?

Comment: Нет, после установки линукса было написано перезагрузить или продолжить знакмоство, нажал перезагрузить - открылся grub2 все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В консоли GRUB'а:

```
set pager=1
ls
```

Вылезет список разделов на диске. Нужно среди них найти раздел с убунтой. Смотреть содержимое раздела можно командой вида `ls (hd0,1)/` (вместо `hd0,1` - название раздела).

Предположим, убунта стоит на `(hd0,1)`, на `/dev/sda1` (вместо обоих поставьте свои разделы):

```
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img
boot
```

Если убунта нормально запустится, нужно сделать

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo updage-grub
```

Теперь после перезагрузки должна быть нормальная менюшка grub'а.

---

У меня такая проблема была вот в какой ситуации:

- Пытаюсь сделать dual-boot с убунтой и виндой.
- Винда установлена в legacy-режиме (т.е. не UEFI).
- В биосе (или как это правильно назвать) режим загрузки выставлен в "UEFI or legacy".
- Live-USB с убунтой умеет грузиться в обоих режимах, и при таких настроках она грузилась в UEFI.
- Соответственно, убунта устанавливалась с расчетом на UEFI, не могла нормально настроить GRUB, и возникала ошибка при установке.

Описанные выше манипуляции с GRUB'ом помогали, но поскольку установка завершалась ненормально, были небольшие проблемы: язык интерфейса нужно было вручную переключать на русский, оставались какие-то лишние пакеты, ...

Правильное решение было - выставить режим загрузки в "legacy only" и переустановить убунту.

Comment: Пытался сделать такое много раз. Под конец не мог найти путь к какому то /cow, но попробую еще раз, отпишусь

Comment: Помогло, cпасибо. И вопрос, всегда возникают такие проблемы при установке линукса? Может ли она просто взять и поставиться? А то всегда, когда пытался установить ее, всегда были проблемы

Comment: @RumeOne *"всегда возникают такие проблемы при установке линукса?"* Ну это как повезет. Есть какие-то стандартные проблемы, решение которых нужно знать.

Comment: Если все работает, жмякните галочку слева от ответа, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.